# Eureka service - locations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am new to spring boot and spring cloud.
I would like to ask if I can have one eureka service for multiple locations (different countries).

For example 
One eureka service and one app service which is running twice - for location SLOVAKIA and another one for location CZECH. 
And then I want to have edge service for that location and for another common services.
Is it possible?

[image: diagram]

config eureka-service

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service

server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

config service-common

```
server:
  port: 9082
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

config service-a

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-a

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
---
spring:
  profiles: sk
server:
  port: 9080
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: skZone
---
spring:
  profiles: cz
server:
  port: 9081
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: czZone
```

config service-a-apigateway

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-a-apigateway
zuul:
  routes:
    book-apigateway:
      serviceId: service-a
      path: /api/**
    book-common-api:
      serviceId: service-common
      path: /common/**

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: sk
server:
  port: 9050
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: skZone

---
spring:
  profiles: cz
server:
  port: 9051
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: czZone
```

[image: eureka instances]

Service-a-apigateway (profile: sk) can call only service-a (profile: sk) and service-common. Profile (cz) has the same behavior. It is good.
But when service-a (profile: sk) is down, service-a-apigateway (profile: sk) can call service-a (profile: cz). This behavior is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it when I had three eureka services  running and one of them (common eureka) replicates to the remaining two services. But I don't know if it's a good idea.

[image: eureka]

Answer (score 0):

I think so, by setting property `eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone` on both zuul edge and service A.

"By default it will be used to locate a server in the same zone as the client..."

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_using_ribbon_with_eureka

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my question.

Comment: I see, you want to restrict it totally, not just prefer it. The default is ZonePreferenceServerListFilter which fallbacks to the other zone. You can probably create your own server list filter and configure it. 


See the source of the ZonePreferenceServerListFilter, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/ZonePreferenceServerListFilter.java

Then reconfigure Ribbon with the new filter. http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client